# Angular 2, custom control is never marked as dirty

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I created a custom control to which I provide the value programmatically because it an image-editor based on cropper.js and the user "uploads" an image via an normal fileinput and I then use the File API to assign the image to my custom control.

here's the code (I removed some cropper.js specific code for readability)

```js
import {
   Component,
   OnInit,
   ViewChild,
   ElementRef,
   ViewEncapsulation,
   forwardRef
} from '@angular/core';

import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
import * as Cropper from 'cropperjs';
import { Photo } from '../entities/photo';

@Component({
   selector: 'image-edit',
   templateUrl: 'image-edit.component.html',
   styleUrls: [
       'image-edit.component.scss',
       '../../../node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.css'
],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
providers: [
    {
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => ImageEditComponent),
        multi: true
    }
   ]
})

export class ImageEditComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

    get value() {
        return this.cropperImage.nativeElement.src;
    }

    set value(v: string) {
        this.cropperImage.nativeElement.src = v;
    }

    public onTouch: () => void;
    public onChange: (_: any) => void;

    @ViewChild('cropperImage')
    private cropperImage: ElementRef;

    private isDisabled: boolean;

    // cropper.js
    private cropper: Cropper;
    private cropperOptions: Cropper.CropperOptions = {};

    public ngOnInit(): void {

        // init cropper.js
    }

    public writeValue(obj: any): void {

        if (obj) {
            this.value = obj;
            this.initializeCropperOrReplaceImage();
        }
    }

    public registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    public registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouch = fn;
    }

    public setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
       this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
    }

    private initializeCropperOrReplaceImage(): void {

        if (!this.isCropperInitialized) {
            this.cropper = new Cropper(this.cropperImage.nativeElement, this.cropperOptions);
            this.isCropperInitialized = true;
        }
        else {
            this.cropper.replace(this.cropperImage.nativeElement.src);
        }

        URL.revokeObjectURL(this.cropperImage.nativeElement.src);
    }
}
```

here's the template

```html
<image-edit [hidden]="!photo.data" #photoData="ngModel" name="photoData" [(ngModel)]="photo.data" validateMinImageDimensions minWidth="300" minHeight="400">
 </image-edit>
```

Unfortunately my control is never dirty or touched.
I tried to extend AbstractForm and set dirty myself but it didnt work. It remains undirty and untouched.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I removed the call to `onTouch` and `onChange` in `writeValue` because according to @n00dl3 answer and comment (see there) it is not a good solution.

Comment: please add your component's template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never call `this.onTouch()` in your component, so your input cannot be marked as touched neither dirty....

So to clarify, you need to manually call `this.onTouch()` when you consider the data has been changed by the user (not by the model), so you should avoid calling `onTouch` inside the `writeValue` method.

Instead you should listen to the eventual events that your user may trigger when dealing with (without necessarily changing) the value you are handling (maybe just after a focus on a regular `input` element).

I guess there is a way to know that the user has cropped the image inside your `Cropper` library like passing a `complete` callback, in the initialization options. You need to call the `onTouch` method from this callback or whenever you think your input should be marked as touched (maybe clicking on the image, or even just hovering it).

Comment: that was it, I needed to call `onTouch()` and `onChange(obj)` in `writeValue`.
I updated the question with code

Comment: it does not make sense to use these in `writeValue`, `writeValue` is called when the model updates the view, you should call these callbacks when you have cropped the image.

Comment: thanks for the additional input, I'll have a look at it

Comment: @n00dl3 do you know where can I get more details on when `writeValue` is invoked. In some tutorials I found that also invokes change callbacks, in others not. Some say `writeValue` is invoked upon programmatic changes, not user changes. Just looking for some "final" definition. Thanks

Comment: @Arikael Did you get the solution for this issue? I want to get touch event but I am not getting touched or dirty on my custom control. I have copy pasted your touch method function but where should I call this.onTouch() ?

Comment: @HardikDG you just need to listen to events inside your custom input and call manually `onTouch()` when you consider it has been touched.

Comment: @HardikDG I updated my answer with more details if it helps.

Comment: @n00dl3 Thanks for the update. I have put it at blur event of the input as per my requirement and it is working as per my expectation.